# Paste properly in contenteditable html table

Tags: javascript

I am having html table with conteneditable. Now when I am pasting data into HTML table then table creates rows instead of columns. Please take a look at my code. I am not able to get what javascript I should use to complete the task.

```html
<table style="width:100%" onpaste="myFunction()" contenteditable>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>66</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("pasted")
}
</script>

<style>
td, th { border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;}
</style>
```

The table is looking something like this when I am pasting 3 column and 4 rows data from excel sheet into HTML table.
[image]